# Return Viewbag.Message without view

Tags: c#, alert, message, viewbag

Can I return /send Viewbag.Message without returning a view? I have an sql parameter from a stored procedure which returns a message and I want to display that message as an alert in my view. Can I use `Viewbag.Message` if I do not return a view?

```
SqlParameter messagePar = new SqlParameter("@message", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
messagePar.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(messagePar);

string cmdMessage = cmd.Parameters["@message"].Value.ToString();
ViewBag.Message = String.Format(cmdMessage);

return Json(dataSource);
```

Any other suggestions how to return the message besides with viewbag?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because you are returning a JSON response. Where would the message be and how would it show up as an alert without being part of the response in some sense?

Comment: Are you using api for this? That's why there is no view? or It is an action in mvc controller that doesn't have any view? Tell us more about who you wan't to show it on your user facing page?